# ASP.NET Core Get Json Array using IConfiguration AND with DI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, config

I have a need to resolve in Microsoft DI, an array of elements in config.

```
{
  "Providers": [
    {
      "Name": "",
      "Url": ""
    },
    {
      "Name": "",
      "Url": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I do this:

```
foreach (var p in builder.Configuration.GetSection("Providers").Get<List<Provider>>())
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(p);
```

The problem is that inside the model, the model also uses DI components:

```
  public Provider(HttpClient httpClient, IMapper mapper, ILogger logger)
```

And as a result, the configuration cannot be completed (there are no DI components yet).
What can be done in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The solution (or 'trick' so you will) is to *split the data from the component* by moving the data to a different data object (or DTO). This allows the data being loaded from the configuration while the `Provider` component is being loaded from the DI system.

For instance:

```cs
// Data container constructor
public ProviderData(string name, string url)

// Component constructor (notice the extra ctor argument)
public Provider(
    HttpClient httpClient, IMapper mapper, ILogger logger, ProviderData data)
  
// Inside your Composition Root
List<ProviderData> providerDatas =
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Providers").Get<List<ProviderData>>();
  
foreach (ProviderData data in providerDatas)
{
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => new Provider(
        httpClient: sp.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>(),
        mapper: sp.GetRequiredService<IMapper>(),
        logger: sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Provider>>(),
        data: data));
}
```

One warning unrelated to your question though: Prevent injection of `HttpClient` instances into Singleton consumers. [This discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36067) explains the consequences of this. But in short:

> Problem being that HttpClients that are stored for the duration of the app domain can cause several issues, most obvious one being that a Singleton HttpClient doesn't respect DNS changes.

It's, therefore, better to register your `Provider` instances as scoped.

Another option is to have just a single `Provider` and have it provided with a `ProviderData` object on every call. This means that the list of `ProviderData` objects is provided to its consumer. For instance:

```cs
public class ProviderConsumer
{

    public ProviderConsumer(List<ProviderData> data, Provider provider) ...

    public void SomeOperation()
    {
        foreach (var data in this.data)
        {
            this.provider.Operate(data, ...);
        }
    }
}
```

With this design, the `Provider` becomes stateless and uses the name and url of the supplied `ProviderData` object, which is *not* stored. This design simplifies registration, because now only one `Provider` instance is registered. Complexity, however, might be moved to its consumers, and a new intermediate class might need to be created to decouple `Provider` from its consumers. How this looks exactly in practice highly depends on how the consumers use `Provider`.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a fully working Console application that demonstrates my first suggestion:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging();

var providersData = new List<Data> { new("Name1", "Url1"), new("Name2", "Url2") };

foreach (Data data in providersData)
{
    services.AddScoped(sp => new Provider(
        Logger: sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Provider>>(),
        Data: data));
}

var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);

using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
{
    foreach (var provider in scope.ServiceProvider.GetServices<Provider>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{provider.Data}");
    }
}

record Provider(ILogger Logger, Data Data);
record Data(string Name, string Url);
```

When running, this application outputs the following:

```
Data { Name = Name1, Url = Url1 }
Data { Name = Name2, Url = Url2 }
```

Comment: There is a problem: it says that ProviderData is not resolved.
If I do build.Services.AddScoped<ProviderData>();
I end up with 3 elements instead of two.
And if I don’t add AddScoped, it doesn’t work at all))
Why is that?

Comment: The whole idea is to keep `ProviderData` *out of* the DI configuration. Do *not* call `AddScoped<ProviderData>()`.

Comment: if i dont call ProviderData, i get Error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SearchService.Data.ProviderData' while attempting to activate 'SearchService.Data.Provider'.` @steven

Comment: In that case, you are not following the first code sample I provided in my answer.

Comment: `var providers = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Providers").Get<List<Data>>();

foreach (var data in providers)
{
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new Provider(
        httpClient: sp.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>(),
        mapper: sp.GetRequiredService<IMapper>(),
        logger: sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger>(),
        data: data));
} `

`public Provider(HttpClient httpClient, IMapper mapper, ILogger logger, Data data)`

`public Data()
{
}
public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
public string Url { get; set; } = null!;`

I did exactly this

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're doing wrong, as the exception doesn't match the provided code example. But see my update; It demonstrates a fully working example. You should be able to extend it from there into a fully working version that suits your needs.